# Time-weighted average with Pandas

Tags: python, time-series, pandas

What's the most efficient way to calculate the time-weighted average of a TimeSeries in Pandas 0.8? For example, say I want the time-weighted average of `df.y - df.x` as created below:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
times = np.datetime64('2012-05-31 14:00') + np.timedelta64(1, 'ms') * np.cumsum(10**3 * np.random.exponential(size=10**6))
x = np.random.normal(size=10**6)
y = np.random.normal(size=10**6)
df = pandas.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y}, index=times)
```

I feel like this operation should be very easy to do, but everything I've tried involves several messy and slow type conversions.

Answer (score 7):

You can convert `df.index` to integers and use that to compute the average. There is a shortcut `asi8` property that returns an array of int64 values:

```
np.average(df.y - df.x, weights=df.index.asi8)
```

Comment: Thanks! I want to weight the values by the time durations, so I used `np.average((df.y - df.x)[:-1], weights=np.diff(df.index.asi8))`