# Python pandas convert datetime to timestamp effectively through dt accessor

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp

I have a DataFrame with some (hundreds of) million of rows. And I want to convert datetime to timestamp effectively. How can I do it?

My sample `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start=dt.datetime(2016,1,1,0,0,1),
    end=dt.datetime(2016,1,2,0,0,1), freq='H'))\
    .reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'datetime'})
```

which looks like:

```
             datetime
0 2016-01-01 00:00:01
1 2016-01-01 01:00:01
2 2016-01-01 02:00:01
3 2016-01-01 03:00:01
4 2016-01-01 04:00:01
```

Now I convert datetime to timestamp value-by-value with `.apply()` but it takes a very long time (some hours) if I have some (hundreds of) million rows:

```
df['ts'] = df[['datetime']].apply(lambda x: x[0].timestamp(), axis=1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
             datetime          ts
0 2016-01-01 00:00:01  1451602801
1 2016-01-01 01:00:01  1451606401
2 2016-01-01 02:00:01  1451610001
3 2016-01-01 03:00:01  1451613601
4 2016-01-01 04:00:01  1451617201
```

The above result is what I want.

If I try to use the `.dt` accessor of `pandas.Series` then I get error message:

```
df['ts'] = df['datetime'].dt.timestamp
```

> AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute
> 'timestamp'

If I try to create eg. the date parts of datetimes with the `.dt` accessor then it is much faster then using `.apply()`:

```
df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.date
```

Output:

```
             datetime          ts        date
0 2016-01-01 00:00:01  1451602801  2016-01-01
1 2016-01-01 01:00:01  1451606401  2016-01-01
2 2016-01-01 02:00:01  1451610001  2016-01-01
3 2016-01-01 03:00:01  1451613601  2016-01-01
4 2016-01-01 04:00:01  1451617201  2016-01-01
```

I want something similar with timestamps...

But I don't really understand the official documentation: it talks about "[Converting to Timestamps](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-to-timestamps)" but I don't see any timestamps there; it just talks about converting to datetime with `pd.to_datetime()` but not to timestamp...

`pandas.Timestamp` constructor also doesn't work (returns with the below error):

```
df['ts2'] = pd.Timestamp(df['datetime'])
```

> TypeError: Cannot convert input to Timestamp

[`pandas.Series.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_timestamp.html) also makes something totally different from what I want:

```
df['ts3'] = df['datetime'].to_timestamp
```

Output:

```
             datetime          ts                                                ts3
0 2016-01-01 00:00:01  1451602801  <bound method Series.to_timestamp of 0    2016...
1 2016-01-01 01:00:01  1451606401  <bound method Series.to_timestamp of 0    2016...
2 2016-01-01 02:00:01  1451610001  <bound method Series.to_timestamp of 0    2016...
3 2016-01-01 03:00:01  1451613601  <bound method Series.to_timestamp of 0    2016...
4 2016-01-01 04:00:01  1451617201  <bound method Series.to_timestamp of 0    2016...
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I think you need convert first to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) and cast to `int64` - output is in `ns`, so need divide by `10 ** 9`:

```
df['ts'] = df.datetime.values.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9
print (df)
              datetime          ts
0  2016-01-01 00:00:01  1451606401
1  2016-01-01 01:00:01  1451610001
2  2016-01-01 02:00:01  1451613601
3  2016-01-01 03:00:01  1451617201
4  2016-01-01 04:00:01  1451620801
5  2016-01-01 05:00:01  1451624401
6  2016-01-01 06:00:01  1451628001
7  2016-01-01 07:00:01  1451631601
8  2016-01-01 08:00:01  1451635201
9  2016-01-01 09:00:01  1451638801
10 2016-01-01 10:00:01  1451642401
11 2016-01-01 11:00:01  1451646001
12 2016-01-01 12:00:01  1451649601
13 2016-01-01 13:00:01  1451653201
14 2016-01-01 14:00:01  1451656801
15 2016-01-01 15:00:01  1451660401
16 2016-01-01 16:00:01  1451664001
17 2016-01-01 17:00:01  1451667601
18 2016-01-01 18:00:01  1451671201
19 2016-01-01 19:00:01  1451674801
20 2016-01-01 20:00:01  1451678401
21 2016-01-01 21:00:01  1451682001
22 2016-01-01 22:00:01  1451685601
23 2016-01-01 23:00:01  1451689201
24 2016-01-02 00:00:01  1451692801
```

[`to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html) is used for converting [from  period to datetime index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-between-representations).

Comment: Thank you! It converts the datetime column into timestamp, of a dataframe with +300 million rows in less then 5 seconds!!!

Answer (score 19):

I think you should not use apply, 
simply `astype` would be fine:

```
df['ts'] = df.datetime.astype('int64') // 10**9
```

Answer (score 13):

There's also another method to do this using the "hidden" attribute of `DatetimeIndex` called `asi8`, which creates an integer timestamp.

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(df.datetime).asi8
```

Wes McKinney suggested it in this tangentially related stackoverflow question linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839701/time-weighted-average-with-pandas)

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use numpy you can use pure pandas conversions

```
df['ts'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['datetime'], unit='ns').dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
```

Comment: converting a datetime to a timedelta is not a meaningful operation, is it?

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of correct answers just be mindful of the deprecation notice on using `astype`. The recommended way of doing this now is:

```
df['ts'] = df.datetime.view('int64')
```

Comment: Strange, I get the exact opposite: `FutureWarning: Series.view is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use astype as an alternative to change the dtype.`

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to convert pandas.datetime to unix timestamp is:
`df['datetime'].values.tolist()`

Comment: Worked for me, most of the other solutions don't handle NaT but this one does and avoids astype.

Answer (score 1):

Another [option](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) is to use `pandas.to_numeric`:

```
df['datetime'] = pandas.to_numeric(df['datetime'].values) / 10 ** 9
```

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to use a lambda expressions like such

```
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x))
```

Comment: That is very slow, for the same reason.

Comment: I recommend to avoid apply because it is in fact for cycle. Try to use vector pandas solution I mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54429530/1683626