# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'datetime'

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting the following error for the code below:

```
import time
import datetime
from pyculiarity import detect_ts
import pandas as pd



data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols=['date', 'money_spent'])
data = data[['date', 'money_spent']]
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data['date'] = (data['date'] - dt.datetime(1970,1,1)).dt.total_seconds()
results = detect_ts(data, max_anoms=0.05, alpha=0.001, direction='both')
```

My dataframe has two columns and it looks like this:

```
date                       money_spent
2015-08-05 00:59:19           11.94
2015-10-29 18:23:04            5.76
2015-10-25 17:50:48           25.84
2015-09-05 17:39:43           68.89
```

To run the anomaly detection code, it says the following:

```
The input timestamp column must be a float or integer of the unix timestamp, not date
                                time columns, date strings or pd.TimeStamp columns.
```

So, I tried following the same using the code above. 
However, I keep getting this error.

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

I updated pandas as that was a solution in one of the other SO posts similar to this. But I still keep getting this error. 
Any help will be much appreciated! thanks!

Comment: What is `dt` in `dt.datetime(1970,1,1))`?

Comment: Where is `dt` defined at all?

Answer (score 4):

easy little gingerbread, use this column instead

`df['other_date'] = df['date'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9`

Comment: Good answer, but you should explain this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881876/python-pandas-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-effectively-through-dt-accessor for details