# How to check for missing values for a TimeSeries Data(Monthly Data)?

Tags: python, time-series, missing-data

Example:

|  | DATE | ENERGY_INDEX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01/1939 | 3.3842 |
| 1 | 02/1939 | 3.4100 |
| 2 | 03/1939 | 3.4875 |
| 3 | 04/1939 | 3.5133 |
| 4 | 05/1939 | 3.5133 |

How to check whether data for any month is being missed in the timeseries data?

[image]

My approach to find the missing values:

```
df['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],format='%m/%Y')
df.index=df['DATE']
df['DATE'].max()-df['DATE'].min()` - output - Timedelta('29463 days 00:00:00')
df.shape - output - (969,2)
```

Actually, `df['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'],format='%m/%Y')` is adding the date parameter in the date.

Comment: Hey @JCaesar, please find my tried out approach in the edited post

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Pandas dataframe :

```
!pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
main_na = pd.Dataframe(your_datas) #Where your_datas is your list or np array
main_na = main_df.notna()
for col in main_na.columns:
    diff = len(main_na[col]) - main_na.count()[col]
    if diff > 0:
        print( f"{len(main_na[col]) - main_na.count()[col]} NaN found in column {col}")
main_df.ffill(inplace=True)
main_df.dropna()
```

This code, that I often use, prints the number of NaN in your data

But if you are in a case where you might have missing rows you should use your date column to create a new timestamp column (take a look here : [Python pandas convert datetime to timestamp effectively through dt accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881876/python-pandas-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-effectively-through-dt-accessor) ). And then set this new column as the index of your dataframe using :

```
main_df.set_index("name of your new timestamp colums")
```

and do this :

```
main_df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)
time_df = main_df.copy()
time_df["diff"] = time_df.index
time_df["diff"] = time_df["diff"]-time_df["diff"].shift(1)
time_df = time_df["diff"]
print(time_df.value_counts())
```

It will display the timestamp difference between each of your rows like this for exemple :

```
900000.0      68383
4500000.0         3
8100000.0         2
9900000.0         2
17100000.0        2
21600000.0        1
13500000.0        1
14400000.0        1
5400000.0         1
6300000.0         1
Name: diff, dtype: int64
```

With the time difference as the left column and the number of case as the right column.