# Convert CSV row date record of type string into unixstamp and load into json - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert date from my csv into Unix stamp and load into json

```
"bFlag","date"
"TRUE", "10/8/2022"
"FALSE","11/8/2022"
```

desired output:

```
{
 {
  bFlag: True
  date : 1660082400000
 },
 {
  bFlag: False
  date : 1660168800000
 }
}
```

my code,

```
import csv
import json
import time
import datetime


#### Transforming Date String into Unix Timestamp ###
def transform_date(ts):
    return time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple()) * 1000


def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []

    # read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:

        ###### Transforming True and False strings into Boolean values
        csvReader = [[True if row[field] == 'TRUE' else
                      False if row[field] == 'FALSE' else
                     row[field] for field in row] for row in csv.DictReader(csvf)]


        
        for row in csvReader:
            # adding python dict to json array
            transRow = transform_row(row)
            jsonArray.append(transRow)

    
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)
```

I want to use transform_date(ts) function when reading data from csv and convert date string into timestamp and before adding it to dictionary.

Any suggestion how to use this, is it possible ?

Comment: shouldn't be the 2nd bflag in the json a "false" ?

Comment: yes, it's just a sample data. my mistake. Corrected it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pandas convert datetime to timestamp effectively through dt accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881876/python-pandas-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-effectively-through-dt-accessor)

Comment: Please select or comment on an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think with pandas it is quite easy to accomplish what you are trying.
the converting to timestamp is answert [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40881958/15521392).

```py
# Input:
df = pd.read_table(
        StringIO("""bFlag   date
TRUE    10/8/2022
FALSE   11/8/2022"""), parse_dates=['date'])

# you read your input from csv file, you want to do something like this:
# df = pd.read_csv(csvfilepath, parse_dates=['date'])

# converting datetime to timestamp
df['date'] = df['date'].values.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9
print(df)
```

Output `df`:

```
   bFlag         date
0   TRUE   1665187200
1  FALSE   1667865600
```

Then convert your `df` to json with `to_json` with the orient of `records` (see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) on the different ways you can build your json data)

```py
res = df.to_json(orient='records')
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
    "bFlag ": "TRUE ", 
    "date": 1665187200
    }, 
    {
        "bFlag ": "FALSE ", 
        "date": 1667865600
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Pandas library, it is very robust and probably the preferred way to manipulate data with python. Below we simply generate the data frame from a dictionary. You can see in commented code how to read a csv with `pd.read_csv`.

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'bflag':[True, False],
    'date':['10/8/2022', '11/8/2022']
})

# or from file
# df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file")

df['timestamp'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x : pd.Timestamp(x).timestamp())
df.head()
```

The function pd.Timestamp() is provided by pandas. We "apply" a lambda function to every row of the 'date' series. The lambda function converts string to a timestamp object, and returns the .timestamp() value of that object to be saved in a new series called timestamp.

Here is the output

```
    bflag   date    timestamp
0   True    10/8/2022   1.665187e+09
1   False   11/8/2022   1.667866e+09
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.timestamp.html

Now for Json, your desired output looks invalid because your dicts are not in a list or they do not have a key. You can use pandas to generate valid json, each dict has a key.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

You can add the path_or_buf param to to_json to write to a file instead of a string.

```
print(df[['bflag', 'timestamp']].to_json(orient='index'))

# prints {"0":{"bflag":true,"timestamp":1665187200.0},"1":{"bflag":false,"timestamp":1667865600.0}}
```