# Shapelet discovery and transformation algorithm implementation

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

I would like to know about any existing implementation(library , code) for shapelet discovery and transform in python to discover anomalies.
for the following kind of data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iknHo.png)

Comment: use pandas.to_datetime

Answer (score 1):

```
pandas.to_datetime(df["TS"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Answer (score 0):

Say this is your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'TS': pd.date_range(
    start='2018-03-01 15:34:51.347340', periods=5, freq='100ms').astype(str)})
print(df)
print(type(df['TS'][0]))

#
                           TS
0  2018-03-01 15:34:51.347340
1  2018-03-01 15:34:51.447340
2  2018-03-01 15:34:51.547340
3  2018-03-01 15:34:51.647340
4  2018-03-01 15:34:51.747340
<class 'str'>
```

Straightforward method would be just using apply:

```
df['TS'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') \
            .timestamp() * 1000).astype('int64')

0    1519907691347
1    1519907691447
2    1519907691547
3    1519907691647
4    1519907691747
Name: TS, dtype: int64
```

Better approach, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881876/python-pandas-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-effectively-through-dt-accessor/54429530#54429530):

```
pd.to_datetime(df['TS']).astype('int64') // 10 ** 6
```

P.S. It's usually appropriate to provide your original data (column) created in code rather as a simple text, for responder's convenience.

Comment: HI, Thanks for ur help, now could u please tell me how to replace this new coulmn with old one in TS

Comment: You can just reassign column, like this: `df['TS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TS']).astype('int64') // 10 ** 6`.